How to notify the file name when copying or moving a file using drag an drop on linux
i would like to implement a functionality that when moving a file from one directory to another by dragging and dropping ,i could get the name of the file.i want to know if there is any way to implement this using X11 interface,please give me a piece of example code i possible.

Don't know if it's what you are looking for (but it should be related); there's inotify.

inotify is not a perfect solution, cuz in my case , i could move or copy any files in any arbitrary directory @Jesper Juhl

There is no completely universal method. And this method usually work:
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE will be set to _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DND when drag and drog a window. You may select PropertyNotify event, and then you can get the window ID when receive _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE property notify. XFetchName to get window name, it usually equal to file name.
